# WPF XAML, Re-Use a color / solidbrush in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some colors in my WPF C# app, which I want to re-use. To avoid double typing (and maintaining issues).

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mybackground">#ffffff</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myforeground">#000000</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderBackground">#000000</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderForeground">#ffffff</SolidColorBrush>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

how can I re-use the `mybackground` or `myforeground` in other brushes?

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mybackground">#ffffff</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myforeground">#000000</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderBackground">{StaticResource myforeground}/SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderForeground">{StaticResource mybackground}/SolidColorBrush>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

HINT: The header use the fore- and background color toggeld to the main content.

I tried also sth. like

```xml
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderBackground" Color="{StaticResource myforeground}"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderForeground" Color="{StaticResource mybackground}"></SolidColorBrush>
```

put here I get the obvious warning `incompatible type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to reuse colors, define Color as resource:

```
<Color x:Key="red">#FF0000</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ErrorBrush" Color="{StaticResource red}"/>
```